# Allow a user to create folders and linked reports, but not "real" reports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have a need to allow certain users the ability to create folders and linked reports within specified folders, but I don't want them to be able to put actual reports in those folders. Is there a magic combination of permissions I can put on a role that will allow this? I'm assuming the "Create linked reports" permission applies to the source report that's being linked, and I'm not sure if linked reports fall under "Manage reports" or "Manage resources".

(For the curious, I want to be able to differentiate between the people developing and deploying reports to a designated location, and people linking those reports to directories that certain end users will have access to.)

**Edit**:

Just to make it clearer what I'm trying to do... Say I've got two directories on the report server: Base Reports, and Sales Department. I want the developers to be able to create reports in Base Reports (no problem there). I also want to allow another group to be able to create linked reports in Sales Department which are based on reports within Base Reports. I *do not* want this group to be able to create actual reports within Sales Department.

In order to allow the second group to create linked reports based on what's in Base Reports, I set Create Linked Reports permission on the Base Reports directory. What do I have to set on Sales Department to allow them to put the linked reports in there, without allowing them to create actual reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As [per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160344.aspx)

> Create linked reports | Reports | Create Link, Read Properties
>   ...
>   Manage folders | Folders | Create Folder, Delete Update Properties, Read Properties

From the same link, one can see that "Create linked reports" does not infer or grant the separate permission "Manage reports"

Comment: As far as I can tell, Create Linked Reports is assigned on the source report, and grants the ability to create linked reports based on that report, but it does *not* seem to grant the ability to create linked reports within a designated directory. So far I haven't been able to find a specific permission for that based on experimentation.

Comment: @db2: it should be on the folder. You don't permission individual items unless you want a world of hurt. As long the original report is visible. I can't test also, I'm sorry

Comment: I don't set the permissions on the reports; I set them on the directories, and they roll down to the reports. The Create Linked Reports permission seems to determine which reports can be used as the basis for creating a linked report, not *where* those linked reports are allowed to be created. It seems like I have to grant Manage Reports on a directory to allow placing linked reports in it, but I don't want to also allow placing the actual reports there.